# How can I open .ttf font in SDL2_ttf?

Tags: c++, sdl-2, relative-path, sdl-ttf

I'm building simple SDL2 project on Windows, and I want to print some text on SDL2 screen.
It works with absolute path, but I want to use relative path. I've tried relative path on `TTF_OpenFont` but it returns `nullptr`.

**Project directory:**

```
Project Directory
├─bin
│  └─debug
│      main.exe
│      SDL2.dll
│      SDL2_image.dll
│      SDL2_ttf.dll
│
├─res
│      font.ttf
│
└─src
       main.cpp
       renderwindow.cpp
       renderwindow.hpp
```

**renderwindow.cpp:**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_ttf.h>

//...

TTF_Font *font = TTF_OpenFont("../res/font.ttf", 16);
if (font == nullptr)
{
    std::cout << "Font couldn't load." << std::endl;
}

//... font displaying stuff
```

**Output:**

```
Font couldn't load.
```

I don't know weather relative path starts at wherer cpp file is or executable file is so, I tried both.
`TTF_OpenFont("../res/font.ttf", 16)` and `TTF_OpenFont("../../res/font.ttf", 16)`
And, sicne I'm on Windows, I tired with different directory separator by replacing `/` with `\\`.
But none of them worked.

Comment: ***I don't know weather relative path starts at wherer cpp file is or executable file is so***  It does not depend on the location of the cpp file, it depends on how you are running your executable. It depends on the current working directory when your program is executed. Some IDEs will set the current working directory to the location of the executable however others like Visual Studio Community will set a different location. For VS Community / Enterprise / Pro the default when you run inside the IDE is $(ProjectDir) which is a VS variable that contains the folder where the project exists.

Comment: You need to figure out where the working directory of the program is and adjust the path accordingly. If it is the `debug` directory then you'd need `../../res/font.ttf` How are you running the program?

Comment: You can use [`std::filesystem::current_path()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/current_path) to grab the [current working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory).

Comment: I'm compling my code with msys2 mingw64 g++, and I'v just tested `std::filesystem::current_path()` and it returns my project root. I think it happen because I'm running them wiht powershell on root dir maybe? So I just put `./res/font.ttf` and it worked.